# recyclerview android developer tutorial error android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android

I was following android [recycler tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) and I had the below error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                             at com.ji.www.i.RecycleAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecycleAdapter.java:33)
                                                                             at com.ji.www.i.RecycleAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecycleAdapter.java:12)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5288)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4551)
```

this is the code

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private String[] mDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(TextView v){

        super(v);
            mTextView=v;
    }
    }
    public RecycleAdapter(String[] myDataset)
    {
        mDataset =myDataset;
    }
    @Override
    public RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                .inflate(R.layout.my_textview, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh=new ViewHolder((TextView)v);
        return vh;
    }
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder ,int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

this is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Insert here" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `ViewHolder` constructor so you can get the reference to the `TextView` inside your layout.

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private String[] mDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View v){

            super(v);
            TextView mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            this.mTextView = mTextView;
        }
    }
    public RecycleAdapter(String[] myDataset)
    {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }
    @Override
    public RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_textview, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh= new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder ,int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Moudiz That example supposes a different layout declared in xml file

Comment: I tried tour code , i am still facing the error on 'v' in this code viewholder vh = new ViewHolder(v): vannot be applied to android view

Comment: @Moudiz did you try the whole updated code? There are multiple edits

Comment: Yes i changed in the constructor and in layoutinflater viewholder is there anything else ?

Comment: @Moudiz look at the parameter type in the ViewHolder constructor. I Tested the code I posted and it's working